# uinavigationcontroller navigation bar always hidden

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing an iOS 4 application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I'm using an UINavigationController and I don't want to show Navigation Bar. To do that, I use this code on AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But, this line, `navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;` doesn't work. I don't see navigation bar on first view controller, but I see it on others views.

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved this doing the following:

1. Setting `navController.NavigationBar.hidden = YES`; in AppDelegate, after alloc it.
2. Setting `[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` on `viewWillAppear:` on every viewController that I pust to navController.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]
```

The doc is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Not the cleanest solution but try calling [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO] in the viewWillAppear of the "ViewController" class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the navigationBar has to be set hidden on the view, not on the controller.

Comment: Yes, but if i do that I will see the space occupied by navigation bar empty. In other words, I hide navigation bar, but it lefts a empty space (view doesn't fit entire screen).

Comment: Make sure the view controller's view autoResizingMask is set to allow flexible height.